# How to wait for array of observables from google-cloud-firestore

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

We are building an application where a user can create their own goals or an admin can create a goal and assign it to a user or group of users.

We are trying to display the username of the user who created a specific goal in our application given the goal they created. Each goal has a field that stores the user id of the user that created the goal. In order to do this we have attempted to map the userIds and usernames in an array, however, firestore returns the data as an observable. For some reason the function returns the empty set of usernames before adding the info from the database within the subscribe function.

[Goals Table with blank createdBy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8TMc.png)

1. We tried converting the info from the database to a promise before adding it to our application, but that code fails to run.
2. We also tried to await the data after subscribing to the observable, but the code ends up returning before the code within the subscribe function executes.

1.

```
 async getUserNames(userIds: Array<string>) {
    const usersCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users');
    const userNames = new Set();
    const reads = userIds.map(id => {
      const user$ = usersCollection.doc<User>(id).valueChanges();
      user$.toPromise().then(user => {
        console.log('adding user');
        userNames.add({
          id: user.uid,
          name: user.name
        });
      });
    });
    console.log(userNames);
    await Promise.all(reads);
    return Array.from(userNames.values());
  }
```

2. ```
   async getUserNames(userIds: Array<string>) {
       const usersCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users');
       const userNames = new Set();
       const reads = userIds.map(id => {
         // grab the user
         const user$ = usersCollection.doc<User>(id).valueChanges();
         user$.subscribe(user => {
           console.log('adding user');
           userNames.add({
             id: user.uid,
             name: user.name
           });
         });
       });
       await Promise.all(reads);
       console.log(userNames); // is empty because subscribe hasn't emitted
       return userNames;
     }
   ```

We expected the function to return the test data in our firestore database, however, it ends up blank because the data hasn't been fetched when we display the username.

To recreate clone the repository: 
https://github.com/ChadwickSchool/goal-management-angular/tree/goals-createdBy-error

```
git checkout goals-createdBy-error
npm install
ng serve -o
```

Click on the home button then click on the row with the name Anastasia to reach the page where the problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

I believe 1 didn't work because you need to return the promise in the map on this line: `user$.toPromise().then(user => {`

Here's my version of 1 that uses observables till the end

```
async getUserNames(userIds: string[]) {
  const usersCollection = this.afs.collection<User>('users');
  const userNames = new Set();
  const reads = userIds.map(id => {
    return usersCollection.doc(id).get().pipe(
      tap(doc => {
        const { uid, name } = doc.data() as User;
        userNames.add({
          id: uid,
          name
        })
      })
    );
  });
  await forkJoin(reads).toPromise();
  return Array.from(userNames.values());
}
```